# T-test on ch2 mean intensity

Tags: r, t-test

My data:
[image: Here you can see the data I am working with]I want to perform a t-test on the following data. The date is exported from a software called "Mamut" that we used to tag individual cells. We tagged this cells because they have a fluorescent marker and we have 3 types of cells. Positive, Weak and Negative. Positive are the ones that have the marker, weaks are the ones that have the marker but it is very subtle fluorescence, and negative are the ones with no marker. You can see the data in the image. For each cell we have a CH2 mean intensity value that we want to test through a t-test to see if the analysis that we are going to do is significant which means that the annotations from the tagging are all right.

I need to perform a t-test, it's my first time doing it so I am a bit lost.

I tried doing it through youtube and google tutorials but I am not getting any good result. I have the same data in two columns; the colors of each individual cell and the ch2 mean intensity value if that helps.

Comment: I don't see an image, though it would be helpful if you put the output from `dput(my_data)` (or `dput(my_data[1:25, ])` if your data are really big) in your question - then we could help with your problem.  Also, a t-test is generally a difference between two different means.  Do you have one particular comparison in mind or do you want to do three different t-tests: Positive vs. Weak, Positive vs. Negative and Weak vs. Negative?

Comment: @DaveArmstrong sorry for the incovenience. I added the Image of the data. I need to compare the 3 groups so I will do the three tests.

Comment: The columns do not have the same amount of rows, does that matter? For example, the positive cells are very few compared to the negative.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the different column pairs as `x` and `y` in `t.test()`.  Here's an example with some made-up data:

```r
my_data <- data.frame(
  WOX5neg = runif(100, 100, 300), 
  WOX5weak = c(runif(50, 200, 500), rep(NA, 50)), 
  WOX5high = c(runif(25, 300, 750), rep(NA, 75))
)

t.test(my_data$WOX5neg, my_data$WOX5weak)
#> 
#>  Welch Two Sample t-test
#> 
#> data:  my_data$WOX5neg and my_data$WOX5weak
#> t = -14.328, df = 78.103, p-value < 2.2e-16
#> alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
#> 95 percent confidence interval:
#>  -206.5767 -156.1743
#> sample estimates:
#> mean of x mean of y 
#>  208.3751  389.7506
t.test(my_data$WOX5neg, my_data$WOX5high)
#> 
#>  Welch Two Sample t-test
#> 
#> data:  my_data$WOX5neg and my_data$WOX5high
#> t = -11.309, df = 26.423, p-value = 1.256e-11
#> alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
#> 95 percent confidence interval:
#>  -368.1655 -254.9874
#> sample estimates:
#> mean of x mean of y 
#>  208.3751  519.9515
t.test(my_data$WOX5weak, my_data$WOX5high)
#> 
#>  Welch Two Sample t-test
#> 
#> data:  my_data$WOX5weak and my_data$WOX5high
#> t = -4.4721, df = 32.495, p-value = 8.899e-05
#> alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
#> 95 percent confidence interval:
#>  -189.46908  -70.93274
#> sample estimates:
#> mean of x mean of y 
#>  389.7506  519.9515
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

This test assumes unequal population variances across groups (you could change by setting `var.equal=TRUE`).  In the example, the groups are of different sizes as they have different numbers of non-missing values.  This is not problematic for the test.

Comment: And the p value what does it mean? What is the conclusion you get from the t-test

Comment: Understanding what's going on here will take more than a comment to explain.  I would encourage you to watch a t-test tutorial (e.g., [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pTmLQvMM-1M)) or look at answers on Cross Validated to similar questions (e.g., [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31/what-is-the-meaning-of-p-values-and-t-values-in-statistical-tests)).